# JS error uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I already wrote the code that worked before, after some other additional details on website my script stopped working. I am not sure about reason why i didn't work. I got below error in console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

code :

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.btnsss', function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            var task = "fav";

            $.ajax(
               {
                  type:'GET',
                  url:'process.php',
                  context: this,
                  data: { "id": id, "task": task }
                  if(data === "4"){
                            window.location.href = '/prijava';
                        } else if(data === "1" || data === "2") {
                            alert('Doslo je do greske!');
                        } else {                  
                        success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);

                        $(this).addClass('active');
                        $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-star');
                        $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
                        $(this).removeClass('btnsss').addClass('btnrrr');

                        $.blockUI({ message: ' <center> <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th spin"></span></h1> <p> Ucitavanje. . .</p> </center> ' });  
                        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 500); 
                        }
                  }
               }
            );
    });
    </script>
```

Im also beginner at js, but first time i solved and all worked after some other edits all this scripts stopped work any suggestion?

Comment: Syntax error, Move `if` block inside the `success` callback handler and also `,` is missing after `{ "id": id, "task": task }`

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on how to call `.ajax`.

Comment: does `data: { "id": id, "task": task } if(data === "4"){` look right?

Answer (score 1):

Invalid JavaScript. The if statement is right in the middle of an object declaration. Something more like this might work for you, although I'm not entirely sure what you want the end result to be.

```
{
  type:'GET',
  url:'process.php',
  context: this,
  data: { "id": id, "task": task },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if(data === "4"){
        window.location.href = '/prijava';
    } else if(data === "1" || data === "2") {
        alert('Doslo je do greske!');
    } else { 
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-star');
      $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
      $(this).removeClass('btnsss').addClass('btnrrr');

      $.blockUI({ message: ' <center> <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th spin"></span></h1> <p> Ucitavanje. . .</p> </center> ' });  
      setTimeout($.unblockUI, 500); 
    }
  }
}
```